# How to avoid write locks in RedShift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I experience locks when I try to modify data in redshift table.
It happens when there is an opened transaction.
In such case my application can be locked for hours till the first transaction is either not committed or rollbacked.

What's the best way to avoid it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STV_LOCKS table shows the current locks.

More info:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_LOCKS.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_join_PG_examples.html